Interpreting a windows dmp file using Windbg
Below is the output from Windbg. My PC has been showing BSOD pretty much every time I've used it and I cannot figure out what is causing it. I read to use Windbg to analyse the dmp file but have no idea what any of the output means. Any help would be really appreciated.
6: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (7f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
BugCheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: ffffda0124c57e70
Arg3: fffffb80b47b5fb0
Arg4: fffff80665e64ed9

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2390

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 2721

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 187

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 3802

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 89

    Key  : Analysis.Version.DbgEng
    Value: 10.0.27704.1001

    Key  : Analysis.Version.Description
    Value: 10.2408.27.01 amd64fre

    Key  : Analysis.Version.Ext
    Value: 1.2408.27.1

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.LegacyAPI
    Value: 0x1000007f

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.TargetModel
    Value: 0x1000007f

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.AsUlong
    Value: 1008

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.DiagDataWrittenToHeader
    Value: 1

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.ErrorCode
    Value: 0

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.KernelGeneratedTriageDump
    Value: 1

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.LastLine
    Value: Dump completed successfully.

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.ProgressPercentage
    Value: 0

    Key  : Failure.Bucket
    Value: 0x7f_8_BHDrvx64!unknown_function

    Key  : Failure.Hash
    Value: {b65f7b1f-9e54-0c47-8997-6841a0f014bd}


BUGCHECK_CODE:  7f

BUGCHECK_P1: 8

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffda0124c57e70

BUGCHECK_P3: fffffb80b47b5fb0

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff80665e64ed9

FILE_IN_CAB:  092424-8359-01.dmp

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1008
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffff828f9aa85080

STACK_OVERFLOW: Stack Limit: fffffb80b47b6000. Use (kF) and (!stackusage) to investigate stack usage.

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  Registry

TRAP_FRAME:  fffffb80b47b65d0 -- (.trap 0xfffffb80b47b65d0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=000001dc1fac1000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffb30270333000
rdx=000001dc1fac1000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff806663b4662 rsp=fffffb80b47b6760 rbp=fffffb80b47b68a0
 r8=fffffb80b47b6814  r9=0000000000000000 r10=ffffb30270333000
r11=0000000000000200 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
nt!HvpGetCellPaged+0xa2:
fffff806`663b4662 8b0417          mov     eax,dword ptr [rdi+rdx] ds:000001dc`1fac1000=????????
Resetting default scope

STACK_TEXT:  
fffffb80`b47b5fb0 fffff806`65e64a92     : fffff806`6686bf00 0012011b`0014341b 000b261a`00000001 001b3418`06090608 : nt!MiAcquirePageListLock+0x69
fffffb80`b47b6050 fffff806`65e7220c     : ffffda01`24c2d410 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 fffff806`65f10564 : nt!MiUnlinkPageFromListEx+0x992
fffffb80`b47b6230 fffff806`65e718b6     : fffffb80`b47b63a8 ffff9400`ee0fd608 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiHandleTransitionFault+0x12c
fffffb80`b47b62b0 fffff806`65e6ae53     : fffffb80`b47b63d0 00000000`c0000016 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiResolveTransitionFault+0x156
fffffb80`b47b6370 fffff806`65e67e92     : ffffffff`ffffffff fffff806`00000000 00000000`c0000016 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiDispatchFault+0x553
fffffb80`b47b64b0 fffff806`6602727e     : 00000000`00000003 ffffb302`6a600000 ffffb302`6bff39f0 ffffb302`6e80a8a0 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x152
fffffb80`b47b65d0 fffff806`663b4662     : 00000000`00000000 fffff806`666f26fc ffffb302`6bff39f0 00000000`00000001 : nt!KiPageFault+0x37e
fffffb80`b47b6760 fffff806`663b20d8     : 00000000`6f48cec9 00000000`6f48cec9 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!HvpGetCellPaged+0xa2
fffffb80`b47b67a0 fffff806`662e354d     : ffffb302`6bff39f0 fffffb80`b47b6b20 fffffb80`b47b6a00 fffffb80`b47b6b40 : nt!CmpWalkOneLevel+0x448
fffffb80`b47b68f0 fffff806`662e7765     : fffffb80`0000001c fffffb80`b47b6e30 fffffb80`b47b6db8 00000000`00000000 : nt!CmpDoParseKey+0x17bd
fffffb80`b47b6d40 fffff806`662e97b4     : fffff806`662e7401 ffff828f`00000000 ffff828f`920a6a30 00000000`00000000 : nt!CmpParseKey+0x2e5
fffffb80`b47b6f30 fffff806`662e8162     : ffff828f`920a6a01 fffffb80`b47b7150 00000000`00000240 ffff828f`8cb9f380 : nt!ObpLookupObjectName+0x1104
fffffb80`b47b70c0 fffff806`662e7e24     : 00000000`00000000 ffff828f`8cb9f380 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObOpenObjectByNameEx+0x1f2
fffffb80`b47b71f0 fffff806`66358b49     : ffffffff`800007f4 00000000`00001001 00000000`00000000 fffff806`6602b608 : nt!CmOpenKey+0x2c4
fffffb80`b47b7440 fffff806`6602b608     : 00000000`00000c62 ffffb302`000000c0 ffffb302`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtOpenKey+0x49
fffffb80`b47b7490 fffff806`6601baf0     : fffff806`781aba52 00000000`00000000 fffff806`65e4481e 00000000`0000007a : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
fffffb80`b47b7628 fffff806`781aba52     : 00000000`00000000 fffff806`65e4481e 00000000`0000007a ffffb302`6b374a80 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
fffffb80`b47b7630 00000000`00000000     : fffff806`65e4481e 00000000`0000007a ffffb302`6b374a80 00000000`00000000 : BHDrvx64+0xfba52


SYMBOL_NAME:  BHDrvx64+fba52

MODULE_NAME: BHDrvx64

IMAGE_NAME:  BHDrvx64.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .process /r /p 0xffff828f9aa97140; .thread 0xffff828f9aa85080 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  fba52

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_BHDrvx64!unknown_function

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b65f7b1f-9e54-0c47-8997-6841a0f014bd}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

I have tried memtest86 with no errors, I have used OCCT to stress test the CPU and Memory with no issues. I have used crystal disk and the HDD and SSD show no issues. I have looked at device manager and checked each device for a driver update and there's nothing there.

By simple search you can see next you need to talk to Broadcom support, https://community.broadcom.com/symantecenterprise/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=2611&MessageKey=a75fff6f-7189-4abc-885d-11efeba6193a you hit something similar.

The driver in question bhxxxx appears to be a norton bash driver  try updating  or try running for some time without norton if you have it.  Double faults can be tedious to analyze

I don't see how this is programming related, unless you are a Broadcom developer working on BHDrvx64, in which case you should ask your colleagues.

@ThomasWeller, this is my personal PC. I did not know that stack overflow is only for programming issues. I am simply looking for help as this PC has been crashing daily for 2 years and its very frustrating. I do not know what broadcom is.

Broadcom is the vendor of your network card or antivirus or VMWare ... It's a huge company.

Okay, thank you for explaining. I have removed Norton and it has continued to crash, so are you saying this is an issue with the network card? Just to clarify, I am not a programmer, so I will clearly lack knowledge in this.
